# Calculating absolute position of HTML element not working

Tags: javascript, html

After searching on the internet, I have got these standard methods for finding the actual position of an HTML element. Something like this:

```
function findPos(obj) {
    var curleft = curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        curleft = obj.offsetLeft
        curtop = obj.offsetTop
        while (obj = obj.offsetParent) {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft
            curtop += obj.offsetTop
        }
    }

    return [curleft,curtop];
}
```

I am using it to find position of the 'Like' button on any YouTube video's page, so that I can insert my own 'div' there (using GreaseMonkey). It works perfectly on the simple Youtube version, but not on cosmicpanda version of it([youtube.com/cosmicpanda](http://youtube.com/cosmicpanda)). It's way off in that case. Could someone help me knowing why doesn't it work there?

-

Thanks,
Piyush

Comment: In your code, only `curleft` is a local variable. `curtop` becomes an implicit global variable. Do this instead: `var curleft = 0, curtop = 0;`

Comment: this could help you: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html

Comment: the quirksmode.org link contains almost the same code what I've written above. It works, but only on the simple version of YouTube. There is some design change they've done, which doesn't allow me to get the right position. I have even tried using getBoundingClientRect() which does almost the same thing in a faster and simpler manner, but that has the same result. Please someone go to the cosmicpanda version of youtube using the above link and try to tell why it doesn't work for the Like button on that.

Answer (score 0):

`offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` give you positions relative to the positioned parent, not relative to the entire document.

Your function will have to keep getting offsets recursively until they return `null`, meaning you're at the document level. Then add up all the offsets together to get the total offset.

Comment: Hi mblase75, I guess this is what I'm doing in the example code written above. And it works in simple YouTube. I want to know what's so special about the cosmicpanda version of it, so that it does not return the correct values. Could you take a look into that using Firebug or something else? Thanks...

Comment: Actually, I can't. Work restrictions and all that. Sorry.